# Showing a UITableViewController in a UINavigationController

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I need to create a UITabBarController which will have in a tab a UITableViewController which can be navigated. So, I created the UITabBarController in Interface Builder. I implemented my subclass of UITableViewController as well.

What I can't understand from the Apple documentation is how I should insert my implementation of the UITableViewController in the UITabBarController so that it can also be navigated? Should I add to the UITabBarController the UITableViewController or the UINavigationController? And how do I link the UITableViewController to the UINavigationController?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hierarchy is like this:

- UITabBarController

  - UINavigationController

    - UITableViewController

Screenshot:

[image: table-nav-tab]

To reference the UINavigationController in code you use: self.navigationController

Comment: I thought I already tried this, but now it seems to work :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

line, added

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] and format your text?  Check the [faq] for details on how.